# Unique conflict between deleted records and creation of new records

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, unique-constraint

Well, I am facing uniqueness conflicts, because as I am using softDeletes(), the deleted records present in the database are conflicting with the new registered records, as the name column has the unique attribute and because of this the system does not Allows me to register a new name that is the same as the deleted record, what do I do?

I tried to use the following logic in validate to prevent the system from validating records that have already been deleted:
$request->validate([
'name' => [
'required',
'string',
'max:255',
Rule::unique('aud_etapas_documentos')->where(function ($query) {
$query->whereNull('deleted_at');
}),
],
'icon' => 'required|string|max:255',
'lado_timeline' => 'required|in:left,rigth',
], $messages);
And with that, I hoped that these uniqueness conflicts would no longer occur with records that had already been deleted from the system.

Comment: 1) Don't use `softDelete` as it does not actually delete the record per [SoftDelete](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#soft-deleting). 2) Incorporate the `deleted_at` field into the PK to distinguish the records.

Comment: there seems to be a typo in your code. You have written 'rigth' instead of 'right' in the 'lado_timeline' validation rule. Correcting this typo might solve your problem.

Comment: @KarlHill how could that possibly solve the problem described here?

Comment: You know you can restore soft-deleted records right? The whole point of soft-delete is so you preserve records instead of outright deleting them. As far as I know, it requires manual logic to check if a record exists and is soft-deleted, but if you find one, simply restore it and update any other fields instead of attempting to insert a non-unique copy.

Comment: This is the error that appears when trying to register a new record: SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "aud_etapas_documentos_nome_unique" DETAIL: Key (nome)=(example) already exists. (23505)

Comment: Why do you need soft delete?

Comment: in case important information is deleted and needs to be recovered

Comment: Then you need to drop the unique constraint from the database.

Comment: but is there no logic to bypass this exclusive restriction in cases of records deleted in the system?

Comment: The error you're getting is at the SQL level, since you defined the `UNIQUE` constraint in SQL. You can adjust your `Rule::unique()` logic to handle Soft Deleted records, but unless you remove or modify that check in your database, it won't matter... When you try to insert a duplicate record, it will still fail.

Comment: This: *And with that, I hoped that these uniqueness conflicts would no longer occur with records that had already been deleted from the system* indicates you have no idea of what is going on. The basic fact is that the records are **not deleted** they just have a `deleted_at` timestamp set in the database table. That means all the other values remains the same and present in the table. This in turn means you cannot add a duplicate `name` due to the `UNIQUE` constraint. You choices are remove the `UNIQUE` constraint or add the `deleted_at` field to the PK.

Comment: Another choice is to create a history table and have a `DELETE` trigger on the original table that saves deleted records to the history table.

Comment: yes, I understand that softdelete deletes records only at a logical level, but a colleague of mine said that there was a way to ignore that record even with the unique property defined, anyway I would look for a better strategy to solve this

Comment: I already managed to solve the problem, I decided to remove the unique attribute from the database and leave it only at the validation level, thank you for your collaboration, it was a great help!

Comment: Yes there is way to ignore it and that is by using the `deleted_at` value. A soft deleted value will have that set, while others will not.